# Which is the best maven's plugin to generate a Web Service Client?

Tags: java, jax-ws, axis

I have to generate a WS Client and I can't decide which plugin to use. Until now my options are: jaxb2-maven-plugin, axistools-maven-plugin and jaxws-maven-plugin.

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432859/difference-of-maven-jaxb-plugins it says that maven-jaxb2-plugin is constantly developed and preferred. Why couldn't you use maven-jaxb2-plugin?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> I have to generate a WS Client and I can't decide wich plugin to use. Until now my options are: jaxb2-maven-plugin, axistools-maven-plugin and jaxws-maven-plugin.

First, the **`jaxb2-maven-plugin`** is not really intended to generate WS clients. ELIMINATED.

Second, personally [I wouldn't use Axis even for client development only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588616/java-webservice-client-best-way/3590252#3590252) so I won't recommend using the **`axistools-maven-plugin`**. ELIMINATED.

This leaves us with the JAX-WS RI and the Apache CXF stacks, and their respective Maven plugins: the [JAX-WS Maven Plugin](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/) (instructions to use the JAX-WS Maven Plugin can be found on the [Usage](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/usage.html) page) and the [cxf-codegen-plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html).

Regarding the pros and cons, I would summarize them like this:

- JAX-WS RI is included in Java 6, but the documentation is more "rough" (although [you'll find plenty of tutorials about JAX-WS RI too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533118/getting-started-with-jax-ws)).
- Apache CXF is better documentated and provide more flexibility if you want to go beyond the spec.

At the end, both choices are decent so I suggest to browse the links a bit and to make your own opinion.

Comment: [JAX-WS Maven Plugin](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/) link changed.

Comment: Don't worry guys I got it!

Answer (score 5):

I use jaxws-maven-plugin. In my opinion, JAX-WS is the de-facto standard implementation for WS. It has much better generated code than AXIS, and easier to config and implement. It has Maven and Spring support.

Generating client-side code from wsdl file, in pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-reports-ws-code</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

<!-- This property is used to support having multiple <execution> elements. The plugin has, from some reason, only one timestamp file per the all executions, thus if you have two executions, it doesn't know exactly when to recompile the code. Here we tell it explicitly to have one timestamp file per each execution -->                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/.staleFlag.reports</staleFile>
                        <packageName>com.acme.reports.ws.api</packageName>
                        <wsdlDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>InternalReportsAPIService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <sourceDestDir>${wsdl.generated.source.files.dir}</sourceDestDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

An interface to create the client service bean (this is not auto generated):

```
public interface InternalReportsAPIServiceFactory {

    public InternalReportsAPIService createInternalReportsAPIService();

}
```

Its Bean implementation:

```
public class InternalReportsAPIServiceFactoryBean implements InternalReportsAPIServiceFactory {

    private URL acmeReportsWsdlURL;

    private final static QName V1_QNAME = new QName("http://internal.reports.api.acme.net/v1","InternalReportsAPIService");

    @Override
    public InternalReportsAPIService createInternalReportsAPIService() {
        return new InternalReportsAPIService(acmeReportsWsdlURL, V1_QNAME);
    }

    public void setAcmeReportsWsdlUrl(String acmeReportsWsdlUrl) {
        try {
            this.acmeReportsWsdlURL = new URL(acmeReportsWsdlUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Acme Reports WSDL URL is bad: "+ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea in this bean (used as Spring bean) is to have a singleton for generating a client service code. It requires two inputs: The WSDL url - that is, the actual URL of the server which implements the WSDL. The client service code, upon construction, send a get request for the WSDL at the supplied URL. It then creates the WSDL based on the annotations residing in the auto generated code, and it compares it. I believe this is done to make sure you're running against the correct server version.
So, I've placed the url in a property file accessible to my application, thus I initialize in my Spring application context file.

Here's an example of using the factory to generate a service and then using it:

```
InternalReportsAPIService internalReportsAPIService = acmeReportsWSFactory.createInternalReportsAPIService();
InternalReportsAPI port = internalReportsAPIService.getInternalReportsAPIPort();
```

From here, just use the port variable to call any operation available on the wsdl.

Comment: this didn't work for me. can you put all the aspects of your pom regarding the wsgen and wsimport thanks. by the way it complains about `Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from/to java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1/): No connector available to access repository java.net`

Comment: Old thread but just saying: JAX-WS is not the defacto standard implementation. It's the standard (specification). An implementation is included in the JDK. Another is CXF. Some maven plugins use those tools and more to generate web service clients.

Answer (score 2):

Maven plugins required:

- cxf-java2ws-plugin (JAX-WS to WSDL)
- cxf-codegen-plugin (WSDL to Java)

JAX-WS to WSDL
To generate the WSDL document from the JAX-WS annotated class by configuring cxf-java2ws-plugin with the ‘java2ws’ goal.

Add the cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws dependency and project dependencies required for the JAX-WS annotated class as plugin dependencies.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.1</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
         <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.medici.app</groupId>
         <artifactId>services</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>generate-sources</id>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <configuration>
            <className>com.medici.app.services.WebServiceBean</className>
            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
         </configuration>
         <goals>
            <goal>java2ws</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

WSDL 2 Java
To generate the Java client from the WSDL document by configuring cxf-codegen-plugin with ‘wsdl2java’ goal.

The ‘-p’ argument specifies the package classes .

The generated classes will be placed in the target/generated-sources/cxf folder.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.1</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>process-sources</id>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <configuration>
            <wsdlOptions>
               <wsdlOption>
                  <wsdl>${project.build.directory}/wsdl/WebService.wsdl</wsdl>
                  <extraargs>
                     <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                     <extraarg>com.medici.app.client.model</extraarg>
                  </extraargs>
               </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>
         </configuration>
         <goals>
            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```