# Quickly implement, deploy a Webservice in Java

Tags: java, web-services, integration

I have a large system written in a mixture of C++, Java, Python. I have to interface a very small subset of this system with a web portal using webservice technology. Webservice is not critical and it has to expose 3 or 4 methods.

What is today the quickest way to implement this in Java? I thoughted AXIS+Tomcat. Maybe is there any other newest library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is today the quickest way to implement this in Java? I thoughted AXIS+Tomcat. Maybe is there any other newest library?

Yes, there is a much better way. Forget Axis and go for a JAX-WS stack such as [JAX-WS RI](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) (which is included in Java 6) or [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). Here is the usual HelloWorld service with a test method using the built-in HTTP server of the JDK:

```
package hello;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class Hello {
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + ".";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/WS/Hello", new Hello());
    }
}
```

Just run the `main` method and you're ready to play with the web service.

Of course, you'll want to deploy your web service on a real container for production use. You could go with  GlassFish and just deploy your service (GlassFish bundles a JAX-WS runtime). Or you could pick Jetty or Tomcat and install the chosen runtime on it (JAX-WS RI or Apache CXF). Refer to their respective instructions.

#### Resources

- [Creating a Simple Web Service and Client with JAX-WS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS3.html)
- [JAX-WS Five Minute Tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world)

#### Related question

- [Getting started with JAX-WS...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533118/getting-started-with-jax-ws)

Answer (score 1):

there is also project ["Jersey"](http://jersey.java.net/) the JSR-311 (JAX-RS) reference implementation. A Framework for Web Services implementing the [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) principles, which in my opinion modern Web Services should adhere to.
It got lots of [tutorials](http://www.google.de/#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&q=311+jersey+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=11527b170f447aba) on the web to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Axis2, Apache CXF or Glassfish Metro 2.0 are all pretty up to date and will provide what you need. Spring-WS is probably easier to use than the previous 3, but only if you're already building in the Spring framework. For comparison see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519576/would-you-use-metro-instead-of-axis2
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461921/axis2-versus-sun-metro