# java webservices

Tags: java, web-services

i am beginner of creating web services in java.i saw there are many ways create webservices in java.i am confused by seeing that and all .pl help which one is better.
i am using myeclipse ide.

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888822/quickly-implement-deploy-a-webservice-in-java/3888963#3888963 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533118/getting-started-with-jax-ws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to choose the stack you want to use. You can choose the JAX-WS or Axis implementations of WS. I advice you JAX-WS that is implemented in EJB3 app server too. What kind of Application Server do you want to use? GlassFish, Jboss Nativestack, Metro?

Comment: for this we need only app server or shal i use tomcat

Comment: Tipically if you use Jboss it has a Web Application Server inside and you do not worry about it. Deploy WS onto JBoss is very simple...

Answer (score 0):

I've used JAX-WS for exposing a EJB3 bean as webservice.,With the use of simple annotations we can expose a service.After annotating just deploy the application in JBOSS (I used JBOOS-5).,It has JBOOS-WS tool to produce a WSDL file.Thats it then all you need a client to test a web service.,

Look at this link

- http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4/cxf_jaxws/JAXWSJavaFirst.html

Answer (score -1):

I've been using Eclipse Java EE, glassfish and EJB3's. That's the easiest way I've found so far. I have not tried MyEclipse.

Comment: thankq for your reply  i have experience on myeclipse