# How to modify SOAP request and response in Java?

Tags: java, soap, tags, request

I have soap request. I am using Java code to make the Webservice.

```
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;<br>
import javax.jws.WebMethod;<br>
import javax.jws.WebService;<br>
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;<br>
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;<br>

< soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/s ap/envelope/" xmlns:demo="http://impl.timecapsule.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <impl:registerUser> <br>
         < argo>username Here /argo> <br>
         < arg1>Password Here /arg1> <br>
         < arg2>EMail@gmail.com /arg2> <br>

      < /impl:registerUser><br>
    < /soapenv:Body><br>
< /soapenv:Envelope><br>
```

IN the above soap request , i want to change the request tag `< arg0>`,`< arg1>`, `<arg2>` ....instead of that i need 
 `<username>`,
 `<password>` 
`<email>`  
tags.

Can anybody help me out for java code to make soap request as user defined xml Tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533118/getting-started-with-jax-ws

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.... I got my solution from 1 of the given URL for study... thanks once again....